# Using Rmpfr to round with precision in R

Tags: r, rounding, mpfr

I'm trying to use the `Rmpfr` library with the `round()` function to apply the [round half to even](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Round_half_to_even) rule and achieve correct results, without errors due the finite precision of float point values, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26962575/round-half-to-even-on-decimal).

So far, this is what I've achieved:

```
library(Rmpfr)
x <- c(1.225, 1.2225, 1.22225, 1.222225)
n <- c(2, 3, 4, 5)
round2 <- function(x, n){
  sprintf(paste("%#.", n, "f", sep=""), round(mpfr(as.character(x), 200), n))
}
mapply(round2, x, n)
#[1] "1.22"    "1.222"   "1.2222"  "1.22222"
```

But in some cases I don't get the desired results:

```
round2(1.152, 2)# Should be 1.15
#[1] "1.16"
```

Reading the `Rmpfr` docs, at the `roundMpfr()` function, it says:

> The mpfr class group method Math2 implements a method for round(x, digits) which rounds to
>   decimal digits.

But I can't figure how to use it.

How can I achieve desired round results using `Rmpfr`?

Comment: try roundMpfr() instead of round().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Talking with the maintainer of `Rmpfr` about this issue, looks like it was a bug on the library.

[This commit](https://github.com/cran/Rmpfr/commit/c13c856ede7820f6e2623c5468028e0010d7dd77) fixed the issue.

After running `install.packages("Rmpfr")` to install the updated version of the library, now I get:

```
library(Rmpfr)
sprintf("%#.2f", round(mpfr(1.152, 200),2))
#[1] "1.15"
```

Which is now correct.